# A library for fetching and parsing RSS in client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, library, rss

I'm looking for a JS library I can use to load an RSS feed and easily access the content.

It must be able to run in the browser but not be a jQuery plugin.

Comment: Hmm, define “access the content”, do you want it as data structure you display yourself, or do you just need customisable display, or…?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements.

Comment: Why don't you want a jQuery plugin? (other libraries can provide the same functionality you don't want on JQuery)

Comment: Which RSS format? Or do you mean any kind of Web feed format?

Comment: You don't need a library for that, browsers natively include an XML parser which can chew through RSS no problem.